# Georeference Plug-in not Opening in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

for some reason georeference plug in will not open. I click on it and nothing happens. I have never had any issues with it before. I have also just installed version 2.6.0 to see if that solves issue but it doesn't.

Comment: There is a button at the lower-right corner of QGIS window that opens log messages. The error should be logged there. Add it to your question.

Comment: It IS an exact duplicate. Notice however that the accepted answer was that the problem "went away on its own". I'm not sure that is a great solution to the problem (waiting for it to go away).